# Is $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n+1}$a complex number? What is happening?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, exponentiation, digamma-function

While computing the integral

$$\displaystyle\int_0^1{\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{(2^n)}dx}$$

I easily got to

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n+1}$$

Since this was getting ridiculously hard for me I resigned and asked WolframAlpha which gave me this solution, although without providing a procedure.

[image]

My confusion is unmeasurable. The second addend I believe we can all agree has to do with the antiderivative of $2^n$ but what perplexes me is the nominator, where did it come from and is the complex part of the approximation relevant or just a computer mistake? Any answer is accepted.

Comment: $10^{-5}\times i$ looks like $0$ to me.  Clearly the sum is real, though that doesn't mean complex functions aren't used to approximate it.

Comment: Actually , the display indicates a real number sinc $0.\times 10^{-5}$ is $0$. But even if this were not the case, numerical issues could lead to very small imaginary values since mathworld always assumes complex numbers unless it can calculate exactly.

Comment: It is indeed a numerical issue (regarding the low value of the imaginary part), but it would be interesting to know where does it come from.

Comment: @lulu sure thing, though I find it compelling. I hope this isn't considered "Clickbait"

Comment: WA's imaginary part looks like zero, really.

Comment: @Algoak Why clickbait ? Wolfram Alpha is a computer and answers automatically. There is not a person sending you the answer.

Comment: @Lelouch It is surely from evaluating the complicated expression instead of numerically calculating the sum. Although the result is always real, intermediate results are not.

Comment: @lulu Actually, the sum is calculated exactly (with a complicated expression) and calculating this exact expression causes the weird display.

Comment: @Peter  Well, the formula using the $q-$polygamma function is exact, but then something is done to attach a numerical value to that.  The final number is certainly not exact (not even the real part).

Comment: The accurate numerical value is 0.764499..., which is 1/2 less than the value 1.2644997... provided with 1000 digits in https://oeis.org/A323482 .

Answer (score 3):

Although $\psi_{1/2}^{(0)}$ was passed a non-real argument $z:=1-\frac{i\pi}{\ln2}$, the result $w:=\psi_{1/2}^{(0)}(z)$ is real, as is the series $\frac{w}{\ln2}-1$. Since$$\Gamma_{1/2}(x)=\prod_{j\ge0}\frac{1-2^{-j-1}}{1-2^{-j-x}}2^{x-1}\implies\frac{\psi_{1/2}^{(0)}(x)}{\ln2}=\sum_{j\ge0}\frac{2^x-2^{1-j}}{2^x-2^{-j}},$$if $\Re x\in\frac{i\pi}{\ln2}\Bbb Z$ then $2^x=e^{x\ln2}\in\Bbb R$.